# How to increase my max oil?

Tags: kittens-game

I am at a point in the game where I want to construct a moonbase to begin harvesting unobtanium. However, I need 40k oil, where my max is only 20k right now. For other resources the max is increased by warehouses, harbors (and tradeships) and barns. For oil, it seems like Oil Wells are the only way to increase the oil cap. It feels unnatural, because I have more then enough oil to keep my magneto's and calciners running.

Is it true that the only way increase the oil cap is by building more oil wells, and will there be later (in-game later, not begin developed) another way the cap, for example by a workshop upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paragon and Oil Wells seem to be it for now.  I hold out hope an update will cause Accelerators (with the upgrade) and Harbors (maybe with the Barges upgrade?) to hold Oil as well, or a new upgrade for Harbors would make sense (Tankers?).

Comment: Tankers sounds like a good idead

Comment: @bloodrizer feel free to steal it ^_^

Comment: If someone is reading it years later, that is how tankers appeared in the game.

Comment: @bloodrizer o_O oh um *blushes, goes to load up his village*

Comment: We love you bloodrizer!